# Where did my Wifi adapter go (Ubuntu 19.04)?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 19.04

Today, my laptops wifi randomly stopped working. I went to check the connection and there was no wifi icon to select. In the settings, it just states "No Wifi Adapter Found". 
The `lspci` command returns this:

`codyp@codys-inspiron:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)`

But, I am inexperienced with Ubuntu and I have no clue what I am looking. Why would it disappear in the first place? Right now I have internet through ethernet. 
The `sudo lshw -C network` command outputs this (I assume I should also be seeing a wireless network listed, but I don't):

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enx00000006776a
   serial: 00:00:00:06:77:6a
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.86.200 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

And this is from `ifconfig`:

```
        inet 192.168.86.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.86.255
    inet6 fe80::409:f5be:cd2e:92e3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:00:00:06:77:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 6217  bytes 6523352 (6.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4303  bytes 604422 (604.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 1447  bytes 129014 (129.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1447  bytes 129014 (129.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Please tell me that this is fixable, I just bought this laptop. Is there anyway to just reinstall the driver? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it still in warranty? Contact tech support.

Comment: No there was no warranty.

Comment: Is there an option in the BIOS/EFI to enable or disable wireless? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes^ I JUST got it to work and that’s how

Answer (score 0):

My Wifi adapter appears to disappear really randomly if I put my computer to sleep and wake back up. But this has been a for sure fix every time:

1. Enter BIOS sets up
2. Click wireless settings shown on the left side of the screen
3. Click restore BIOS settings
4. Restart computer